# Redirect files from on server to another server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all files from one server to another server

forexample

www.example.com/file.php 
to 
www.example2.com/files/file.php

```
RedirectPermanent /file.php http://example2.com/files/file.php
```

works great. how can I redirect multiple files with it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, you want to have all links on your old domain, point to a new domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Redirect multiple files from one server to another server, You need to use RedirectMatch directive with regex pattern.

Try this in your example1.com/.htaccess :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://example2.com/files/$1
```